# How do I insert columns without changing cell reference of a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following formula in cell A1 where I am simply adding and subtracting some numbers...

```
  =B1+D1+F1-C1-E1-G1
```

And I repeat this going down to row 100 such that the formula in A2 is...

```
  =B2+D2+F2-C2-E2-G2
```

And so on.  Then I run a macro that inserts two columns in front of column B and places two new numbers in what is now the new columns B and C, with the other six columns moved to the right.  But I want the formula in A1 to reference the same columns as before, not follow the original columns.  How can I do this and also be able to drag the formula from A1 down to A100?

Answer (score 2):

You can use function offset.

See excel help for better uderstanding

Fill this to A1 and drag down.

```
=OFFSET(A1;0;2)+OFFSET(A1;0;4)+OFFSET(A1;0;6)-OFFSET(A1;0;3)-OFFSET(A1;0;5)-OFFSET(A1;0;7)
```

### Update

Sorry, I have non-English version of the Excel where `;` are as separation character in formulas.

In English Excel is it probably with `,`

```
=OFFSET(A1,0,2)+OFFSET(A1,0,4)+OFFSET(A1,0,6)-OFFSET(A1,0,3)-OFFSET(A1,0,5)-OFFSET(A1,0,7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **named formulas**. Simply do this:

1. Select Cell *A1*.
2. On Formulas go to *Define Name*
3. In the dialog put in the *Name box* the name that you want to use. For example: **my_formula**.
4. In the *Refers to* box, write: `=B1+D1+F1-C1-E1-G1` and click *OK*.
5. On *A1* write `=my_formula`, check if the result is correct and then copy to *A2, A3, A4..... A100*.

Now, it doesn't matter if you add columns or remove columns.

If in the future you need to modify the formula go to *Formulas -> Name Manager*.

Comment: Note that when doing this, if you enter the formula by clicking the cells instead of typing in their addresses manually, you will need to remove the `$` signs from the addresses Excel generate, otherwise the named formula will shift when you insert columns.